# Display TIMEDIFF result from mySQL query to webpage

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Me again, guys. The titles is pretty self-explanatory, but for the details:
I want to display the timediff(in hours) results on a webpage but I can't wrap my head around how to do it.
I'm using PHP and Codeigniter for this website.
So far, I have a mySQL database with a table named 'server_log' which looks like:

```
+--------+-----------+--------+---------+------------+-------------+
| log_id | host_name | status | host_id | profile_id | event_date  |
+--------+-----------+-+----------------+------------+-------------+
|   1    | http://...| Online |   1     |      1     | *timestamp* |
+--------+-----------+--------+---------+--------------------------+
```

*It shows also other entries with status "Offline" and "Maintenance".

I have this query to get the entries per user (based on profile_id) w/c are also sorted by status ('Online','Offline', or 'Maintenance'):

```
SELECT * FROM server_log 
WHERE (profile_id=$id AND status='Online')
AND event_date BETWEEN $from_date AND $to_date
ORDER BY event_date,host_id;
```

*the from_date and to_date are results from the webpage which lets the user choose a 'From' and 'To' date to filter the results like a report page.
The problem I have is that after the above query I do not know what I else I need in order to calculate the TIMEDIFF results for each server(host_id) then display them on the webpage. (**I'd like to get the TIMEDIFF between the results after getting the query results for each status**)
How do I get the TIMEDIFF result (integer)?

Simply put, I want the flow to be like this:

```
[1] After 1st query: (SELECT ALL 'Online' for $id)

log_id | host_name  |  status   | host_id | profile_id | event_date
 1    ping.test1        Online      1          2            **
 2    ping.test1        Online      1          2            **
 3    ping.test2        Offline     2          2            **
 4    ping.test2        Offline     2          2            **

[2] After 2nd query: (loop for each host_id)

 log_id | host_name     |  status   | host_id | profile_id | event_date
   1      ping.test1        Online      1          2            **
   2      ping.test1        Online      1          2            **  

-> then calculate diff_date of event_dates

---> then return value to be assigned to $data['reports_ping']

-----> back to [1] but selecting all 'Offline', then 'Maintenance'

-------> if all values are assigned, display $data['reports_ping'] as row (foreach)
```

I would like the results to show something like:

```
    +------------+------------+------------+-------------+-------------+
    | profile_id | host_name  | online_hrs | offline_hrs | maintenance |
    +------------+------------+------------+-------------+-------------+
    |     1      | http://... |     2      |      1      |    0        |
    +------------+------------+------------+-------------+-------------+
```

I'm relatively a beginner and not really that good with CodeIgniter, so any help with this would be REALLY appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: TIMEDIFF meaning different time between event_date and now?

Comment: I'm not quite *catchy*, which one you been updated?

Comment: Added more details above, @Colour Dalnet

Comment: These need to be quoted `'$from_date' AND '$to_date'` if it's not an `int`. Plus removing the quotes for `ORDER BY 'event_date','host_id'` since those are columns `ORDER BY event_date,host_id`

Comment: @Fred-ii- the problem is not with the query, it's working and showing the results. the problem is how to use these queries to show the timediff results so that I can display the int(result) on the webpage. I've added some new lines above for clarity

Answer (score 0):

TIMEDIFF meaning different time between event_date and now? Try this :

```
SELECT *, (event_date - NOW()) as TIMEDIFF FROM server_log 
WHERE (profile_id=$id AND status='Online')
AND event_date BETWEEN $from_date AND $to_date
ORDER BY 'event_date','host_id';
```

-- EDIT --

Is this the logic you want?

```
$temp = null;
foreach($rows){
    $event_date = "select event_date from server_log order by log_id LIMIT 1"; // specify this query using your CI format
    $timediff = $event_date - $temp;
    $temp = $event_date;
}
```

Comment: Post updated ^. I have tried this, but I get a blank result. That's why I've brought the problem here to get expert opinions.

Comment: @LehandroZharos : Did you mean different between event_date in millisecond? and what is criteria? maybe you can write the formula like : `TIMEDIFF = event_date[log_id] - event_date[log_id - 1]`